# Workflow with user selecting Destination doc library

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to implement a Workflow, where the user needs to select a destination document library.

I could figure out two possible ways:

1. Once the user manually starts the workflow, we would display a webpage where he would select the destination document library.
2. we would initially display a webpage. where User would select the destination.
   After clicking a button the workflow would kick start.

Now for possibility "1":
How to redirect from a worlflow to a webpage. [tried Server.Transfer, but failed].

for Possibility "2":
How to start a workflow on button click.

Please also suggest which among the above 2 possibilities is a better solution.

Comment: Can you give some more details please. Is this a sharepoint type workflow or a coded .net 3+ WF based workflow.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a workflow initiation form. Exactly how you implement it and how much functionality can get will depend on the type of workflow you are working on, but you should be able to set up something to choose the destination.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are talking about writing a workflow using Visual Studio. Personally, I would try creating a SharePoint designer workflow first to see if that meets your requirements.

In SharePoint Designer you can [create an initiation form](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA102097781033.aspx) that accepts data from a user when they manually start the workflow. If the out of the box actions don't quite do what you need them to, you can create your own reusable [custom workflow actions](http://www.ideseg.com/AddCustomWorkflowActivitiesToSharePointDesignerPart1.aspx).